# How do I filter a dataframe based on complicated conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Right now my dataframes look like this (I simplified it cause the original has hundreds of rows)

```
import pandas as pd

Winner=[[1938,"Italy"],[1950,"Uruguay"],[2014,"Germany"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(Winner, columns=['Year', 'Winner'])
print(df)

MatchB=[[1938,"Germany",1.0],[1938,"Germany",2.0],[1938,"Brazil",1.0],[1950,"Italy",2.0],[1950,"Spain",2.0],[1950,"Spain",1.0],[1950,"Spain",1.0],[1950,"Brazil",1.0],
[2014,"Italy",2.0],[2014,"Spain",3.0],[2014,"Germany",1.0]]
df2B=pd.DataFrame(MatchB, columns=['Year', 'Away Team Name','Away Team Goals'])
df2B
```

I would like to filter df2B so that I will have the rows where the "Year" and "Away Team Name" match df:

[Filtered List (Simplified)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDOhP.png)

I check google but can't find anything useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge.

```
df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df2B, left_on=["Year", "Winner"], right_on=["Year", "Away Team Name"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Year   Winner Away Team Name  Away Team Goals
0  2014  Germany        Germany              1.0
```